# How do you map members and their responsibilities to an organization?

Tags: django, domain-model, relationships

I'm working on a Django project that tracks arts-related activities, and I'm stuck on the human-resources part of things.

(code below) I have a class `Ensemble` that subclasses `Organization`. `Organization` only has one important field, `name`. `Ensemble` has another field, `players` (a many to many relationship). A player is a `Performer` which has two foreign key fields, `individual` and `instrument`. The idea is that a performer is any individual on a particular instrument--so, e.g., I can be one individual that can be two performers: one on guitar, the other on bass.

The problem is that not all `organization`s are as clean as this. Some `Organization`s will have dancers, for instance (a dance troup), plus any number of generic `Individual`s who do any number of specific tasks not tracked as a specific class (like `Performer`). So at first I was thinking it would be best to just map `Individual`s to the `Organization` through a many to many relationship, create a `Job` class mapping `Individual`s to a `JobCode` class (which might include a row with something like 'performer'), but that doesn't work well if for instance you want to keep track of *which* instrument a performer plays for that particular ensemble, or if they play multiple instruments, I would like to be able to make that explicit. That's why the `Ensemble::players` relationship made sense to me.

So it seems I have an `Organization` class that will never truly be more than abstract, but I still need to be able to track what type of job an `individual` does for an `Organization`. `Ensemble` only makes sense for mapping `Performers` to an `Organization`, but what about `Teacher`s in a `School`? Again, I would like to be able to make it explicit that a bassoon player is teaching bassoon at the school, and not clarinet (even though they might play both). So I can't just map the `Individual` to the `School` organization, right?

Also, this seems like it would be a common problem. Is there a conventional way of dealing with these kinds of relationships? What is the most effective?

**Code:**

```
class Individual(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prefix = models.ForeignKey(Prefix, blank=True, null=True)
    suffix = models.ManyToManyField(Suffix, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone_numbers = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneNumber, blank=True)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)

class Performer(models.Model):
    individual = models.ForeignKey(Individual)
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    founded = models.DateField()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    media = models.ManyToManyField(Upload, blank=True)

class Ensemble(Organization):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Performer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always with business analysis patterns: check out Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/ , more specifically his catalog of Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/ and his further development of those: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/

For dealing with roles he has a dedicated pdf around (probably taken from his book Analysis Design Patterns). IIRC in the book his examples were centered around hospitals, physicians and contracts (or rights to practice in a hospital), but you can get a lot of inspiration from his writings. PDF: http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/roles.pdf (It may take some time to load, the site seems very slow at the moment I write this).

Comment: Thanks. That roles document definitely looks helpful. I think I may have come up with a good solution, but I'll check it against what I read in this paper. Thanks again